# Unable to import csv file into static file using node and expres

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, express

I'm pretty new to node and express, and am trying to integrate some d3 visualizations into my web page. Basically, I have a js file that generates all the d3 stuff, which I then include in my .ejs file.

I'm trying to follow a past project I did with d3, and am trying to import my csv file into my d3 js file. However, I get the error

"Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/csv".

This is my setup:

```js
// user-influence-viz.js

// this line gives error, worked in a past project that didn't use express
import influence_csv from "./influenceByMonth.csv"

const SVG_WIDTH = 600;
const SVG_HEIGHT = 600;

// rest of code below, irrelevant so leaving out to reduce clutter
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Stats</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Stats</h1>
  <div class="display-container">
    <div class="tab-content" id="tab1Content">
      <!-- Data viz goes in here, placed here by d3 code -->
    </div>
    <div class="tab-content">Tab 2 Content</div>
    <div class="tab-content">Tab 3 Content</div>
    <div class="tab-content">Tab 4 Content</div>
  </div>
  
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
  <script type="module" src="user-influence-viz.js" defer></script>
  <script src="javascripts/bundle.js" defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

If this is not the proper way, what is the correct way to go about this? Looked up a bunch of other resources but nothing with this issue, so I may be lacking some basic knowledge. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never seen someone import a non-javascript file in that way. It might be possible, but if so I don't know what the correct syntax is. The documentation for [import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) seems to imply it's only for JS files.

It looks like you're using this client side, so just use a pure-js CSV parse library like [PapaParse](https://github.com/mholt/PapaParse).

[CDN Link](https://unpkg.com/papaparse@5.2.0/papaparse.min.js)

Example usage:

```js
Papa.parse("/whatever/the/path/is/influenceByMonth.csv", {
    download: true,
    complete: function(results) {
        console.log(results);
    }
});
```

There's lots of different libraries to do this, pick your favorite.

If you're worried about a library's load times making your website slow, you can also just request the data with Ajax and parse it yourself — not too difficult unless your data is extremely funky. [Here's a tutorial for that](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/parsing-a-csv-file-with-javascript--cms-25626). This particular tutorial uses jQuery, but it's totally possible to do without it: just use vanilla JS [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) instead of `$.ajax(...)`. Why reinvent the wheel, though?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm just having one issue with the path -- since I am writing client-side code, does it prevent me from accessing my filesystem due to security reasons? I am trying a bunch of different paths to my file but all of them are saying they can't find it. If that's the case, do I have to try to run my d3 code serverside?

Comment: Yes, client side code can not access your local files. Depending on what you’re actually trying to make here, though, you could either make this a desktop Electron application, which can access local files, or you could put the CSV file in the server’s public folder, where the file can be read by a client.